# VF page for inserting and viewing object values

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, standardcontroller, insert

I need to make VF page for inserting new Contacts that shows pageBlockTable of all existing Contacts below. After i add **recordSetVar="contacts"** save  button stops working.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts">
    <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock title="New Contact">
            <apex:pageblockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{! Contact.FirstName }"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! Contact.LastName }"/>        
            <apex:inputField value="{! Contact.Email }"/> 
       </apex:pageblockSection>
              <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
             </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlock title="Contact list">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! contacts }" var="ct">
            <apex:column value="{! ct.FirstName }"/>
            <apex:column value="{! ct.LastName }"/>
            <apex:column value="{! ct.Email }"/>
            <apex:column value="{! ct.Account.Name }"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form >
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make use of Standard Save functionality to create a new record when you are working with StandardListController i.e recordSetVar. Since the page contains all the records returned from recordSetVar.

To achieve your requirement , you need to create a custom controller which returns StandardSetController containing list of records and overriding the Save function as below.

VisualForcePage :

```
<apex:page Controller="CustomAccountController" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:inputtext value="{!AccountName}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveRecord}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="acc">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class CustomAccountController 
{

    public string AccountName {get;set;}

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon 
    {
        get {
            if(setCon == null) 
            {
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account Order By Name asc]));
            }
            return setCon;
        }
        set;
    }

    public List<Account> getAccounts() 
    {
        return (List<Account>) setCon.getRecords();
    }

    public PageReference SaveRecord() 
    {
        Account newAccount = new Account();
        newAccount.Name = AccountName;
        insert newAccount;

        PageReference pageRefer = new PageReference('/apex/CustomAccountsPage');
        pageRefer.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRefer;
    }
}
```